# how to expand a jScrollPane in all four directions?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jscrollpane

I am working on a very simple mind mapping application, and I use a JPanel to draw the structure of the mind map on. The nodes of the mind map are circles, and if you write in a node, the structure expands in that direction. I put my JPanel in a JScrollPane, but my problem is, that I can only expand it downwards, or to the right, but it should be expandable to the left and upwards as well. When my JScrollPane should expand in "negative directions" so upwards or to the left, I tried calculating how many coordinates I shift, and than redrawing the whole graphic, changing the x and y coordinates of everything respectively. But it still did not work, it drew the part that is visible correctly, but then when I scrolled down, the rest of my drawing disappeared.

I hope there is a solution for this, because I've searched for hours and found nothing useful, and because I can't think of any other way to solve this. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When my JScrollPane should expand in "negative directions" so upwards or to the left

You can't have negative coordinates, so you need to translate all the indexes to positive values.

> and if not, I resize the JPanel.

This is the key. You need to override the `getPreferredSize(...)` method of your custom panel to return the appropriate size of the panel after all nodes have been translated to positive values.

Then you invoke:

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

on the panel to make sure the layout manager is invoked and the nodes are repainted.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I couldn't explain my problem correctly, but I actually did, what you wrote! My mistake was that I calculated the new coordinates in the graphics class, so after revalidate and repait was called. I don't even know why... it was such a stupid thing! :) But a simple copy and paste solved the problem, so thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: @DobóAnna `I calculated the new coordinates in the graphics class, so after revalidate and repait was called.` this is correct. You should calculate the coordinates in the graphics class. Then the class should invoke revalidate() and repaint() on itself. Your application code should NOT invoke the revalidate() and repaint().

Comment: Oh I thought, I shouldn't put revalidate() and repaint() in the graphics class! Why is it wrong, that my application calls these methods? I'm fairly new to this topic, so sorry if it's sounds like a stupid question, but what is a button is pressed, for example, and beacuse of this event, I want to repaint the JPanel, than the repaint should be in the actionlistener, isn't it?

Comment: @DobóAnna, Why do you want to repaint() when you click a button?? The painting of the custom class will be the same. The only reason to repaint the class is when you change a property of the class. So therefore you should have a `set???(...)` method that changes the property and then within that method you invoked revalidate() and repaint(). Think of the way all other Swing components work. This is what happens when you invoke setText(), setFont(), setForeground(), setBackground() etc.